# use the conditional format with epplus

Tags: c#, visual-studio, epplus

I´m trying to aplly a conditional format to a an Excel using eppplus, in that case i want to apply a pattern to all odd rows. so i try use the mod function, but not working, i don´t know how to put the formula

```
ExcelAddress _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("A2:Q" + (listSize+ 1));

string _statement = "MOD(ROW();2)=0";
var _cond1 = hoja.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
_cond1.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
_cond1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

_cond1.Formula = _statement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the formula string.  I think you want a `,` instead of that `;`.  So change this:

```
string _statement = "MOD(ROW();2)=0";
```

to this:

```
string _statement = "MOD(ROW(),2)=0";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no, this is not the problem, in my versión of Excel i need to put   ";" not  ",".

I have an Excel 2010 in Spanish so in fact the real formula is 
`string _statement = "RESIDUO(FILA();2)=0";`
but i put in english because more easy for the people to answer.

When i i put the formula in Excel with "=" before the formula Works fine